# Getting the value of a SortedList item / What data structure is more suitable here

Tags: c#, collections

I'm using a SortedList and its GetKey() method. But now I need to be getting the value too using the index as with GetKey(). Is there a more appropriate collection I should be using?

Comment: If my answer didn't help you, please tell me, why, and I try to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the list to be sorted a better data structure would be the generic `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`. Otherwise, an alternative would be a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which doesn't give any guarantee about sorting.
When using the non-generic `SortedList`, you can get a value with the help of the key with the [Item property, i.e. using the key as index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.item.aspx).
When using the generic `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`, you can get a value with help of the key using [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342417.aspx) or again directly using the [key as index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132378.aspx).